# how to insert Redis Key as integer using StackExchange.Redis

Tags: redis, int, stackexchange.redis

i am using StackExchange.Redis client to store my data in redis server 
but while trying to insert key as Integer

`redisDataBase.StringSet(1,"1");`

i got exception , a though in [redis documentation](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro), Redis keys are binary safe, this means that you can use any binary sequence as a key, from a string like "foo" to the content of a JPEG file. The empty string is also a valid key.
[image]

Comment: what exception?

Comment: @GuangshengZuo updated question with image for exception

Answer (score 2):

It is because int cannot be the key, the key should be the type of string or byte[]. You can check out [this page](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/KeysValues) to see more.

And if you want an integer to be a key, you could convert it to a String

```
redisDataBase.StringSet("1","mohammed")
```